# Issues with Nancy Framework for MVC (and NewRelic)

Tags: c#, .net, nancy, newrelic

I just took over a bunch of C# code from another company, and I'm having big trouble getting the first build to work. The code uses a framework called Nancy, instead of MVC. I have never used this framework before, and there might be a real simply answer to my question, and I apllogize if I missed some basic understanding of Nancy, before posting here.

The problem is boiled down to a single class, handling the initialization of the application (I THINK) From what I've read, it's pretty standard Nancy:

```
using System;
using Nancy;
using NewRelicAgent = NewRelic.Api.Agent.NewRelic;
using Nancy.Bootstrapper;
using Nancy.Routing;

public class NewRelicStartup : IApplicationStartup
  {

    private readonly IRouteResolver routeResolver;
    public NewRelicStartup (IRouteResolver routeResolver)
    {
        this.routeResolver = routeResolver;
    }
    public void Initialize(IPipelines pipelines)
    {

        pipelines.BeforeRequest.AddItemToStartOfPipeline(
            context =>
            {
            var route = routeResolver.Resolve(context);
            if (route == null || route.Item1 == null || route.Item1.Description == null) // probably not necessary but don't want the chance of losing visibility on anything
            {
                NewRelicAgent.SetTransactionName(
                    context.Request.Method, 
                    context.Request.Url.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                NewRelicAgent.SetTransactionName(
                    route.Item1.Description.Method,
                    route.Item1.Description.Path);
            }
            return null;
        });

        pipelines.OnError.AddItemToEndOfPipeline(
                (context, ex) => {
                    NewRelicAgent.NoticeError(ex);
                    return null;
                }
        );
    }
}
```

When this code is being build, I get several errors, some of which being:

```
Delegate 'System.Func<Nancy.NancyContext,System.Threading.CancellationToken,System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Nancy.Response>>' does not take 1 arguments

Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'Nancy.PipelineItem<System.Func<Nancy.NancyContext,System.Threading.CancellationToken,System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Nancy.Response>>>' because it is not a delegate type
```

Here is a screenshot of the kind of error I get:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/cigcfc4sfj8batg/Nancy%20Error.PNG

I am 100 % certain, that this is some kind of interpretation issue from Visual Studio's side, since the code is live atm. I just can't build it in VS.

Do any of you have any idea what I am missing, or doing wrong? Remember; the code is working and live atm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing "return null;" to "return (Nancy.Response)null;"

Edit: Sorry, just looked at the screenshot - it's using some properties that have changed in 0.20, so you will either have to manually fix up the code (it's now async at the core), or roll back to 0.19 for now, and re-write that bit of code at a later date.

Edit again: Give this ago:

```
        pipelines.BeforeRequest.AddItemToStartOfPipeline(
        context =>
        {
            var route = routeResolver.Resolve(context);

            if (route == null || route.Route == null || route.Route.Description == null) // probably not necessary but don't want the chance of losing visibility on anything
            {
                NewRelicAgent.SetTransactionName(
                    context.Request.Method,
                    context.Request.Url.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                NewRelicAgent.SetTransactionName(
                    route.Route.Description.Method,
                    route.Route.Description.Path);
            }
            return null;
        });
```

Comment: Still gettting the errors (see https://www.dropbox.com/s/cigcfc4sfj8batg/Nancy%20Error.PNG).

As i said - the code is live and working; so it must be something about my VS, or the DLL files. I don't know.